# REACTJS unable to take input data from form

Tags: reactjs, input

Hi knowledgeable people at StackOverflow,

```
  I'm currently following a REACTJS tutorial and I have no idea how to save the input data that the user types into the input form. What is supposed to happen is that whenever the user clicks the button, it should also take what the user typed and enter it into the todolist. However, all it does is that it displays a timestamp. Please help, it would be very much appreciated. The code is here, it's specifically lines 48-49:
```

Here is the Todos.js file:

```
import React from "react";
import Todo from "../components/Todo";
import * as TodoActions from "../actions/TodoActions";
import TodoStore from "../stores/TodoStore";

export default class Featured extends React.Component {
      constructor(){
        super();
        this.getTodos = this.getTodos.bind(this);
        this.state = {
          todos: TodoStore.getAll(),
          loading: true, 
        };
      }

      componentWillMount(){
        TodoStore.on("change", this.getTodos);
        console.log("count", TodoStore.listenerCount("change"));
      }

      componentWillUnmount(){
        TodoStore.removeListener("change", this.getTodos);
      }

      getTodos(){
        this.setState({
          todos: TodoStore.getAll(),
        });
      }

      reloadTodos(){
        TodoActions.reloadTodos();
      }

      createTodo(){
        TodoActions.createTodo(Date.now());
      }

      render(){
        const {todos} = this.state;

        const TodoComponents = todos.map((todo) => {
          return <Todo key={todo.id} {...todo}/>;
        });

        return(
          <div>
            <button onClick=                {this.createTodo.bind(this)}>CREATE</button>
            <input type="text"/>
            <h1>Todos</h1>
            <ul>{TodoComponents}</ul>
          </div>
          );
      }
    }
```

Here is the TodoActions.js file:

```
import dispatcher from "../dispatcher";

export function createTodo(text){
  dispatcher.dispatch({
    type: "CREATE_TODO",
    text,
  });
}

export function deleteTodo(id){
  dispatcher.dispatch({
    type: "DELETE_TODO",
    id,
  });
}

export function reloadTodos(){


  dispatcher.dispatch({type:"FETCH_TODOS"});
  setTimeout(() => {
    dispatcher.dispatch({type: "RECEIVE_TODOS", todos:[
      {
        id:1234567,
        text: "Work Again",
        complete: false
      },
      {
        id:1234679,
        text:"Go Shopping and Enjoy It Again!",
        complete: true
      },
    ]});
  }, 1000);
}
```

Here is the TodoStore.js file:

```
import {EventEmitter} from "events";
import dispatcher from "../dispatcher";

class TodoStore extends EventEmitter {
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.todos = [
      {
        id:12345,
        text: "Work",
        complete: false
      },
      {
        id:12346,
        text:"Go Shopping and Enjoy It!",
        complete: false
      },
    ];
  }

  createTodo(text){
    const id = Date.now();

    this.todos.push({
      id,
      text,
      complete:false,
    });

    this.emit("change");
  }


  getAll(){
    return this.todos;
  }

  handleActions(action){
    switch(action.type){
      case "CREATE_TODO":{
        this.createTodo(action.text);
        break;
      }
      case "RECEIVE_TODOS":{
        this.todos = action.todos;
        this.emit("change");
        break;
      }
    }
  }

}

const todoStore = new TodoStore;
dispatcher.register(todoStore.handleActions.bind(todoStore));
window.dispatcher = dispatcher;

export default todoStore;
```

I have already searched StackOverflow and also did numerous searches online, and the ReactJS site documentation was a bit confusing. Please help. It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please format your text properly, its really hard to read currently, as its all in one line. Four spaces indicate code formatting, so start your text without them.

Comment: Yeah that's been confusing because when I use the four spaces, and then paste my code, it doesn't work...

Comment: share your TodoActions
TodoStore files

Comment: @Marcode777 each line must be intended by 4 spaces for code blocks

Comment: @PinkieSwirl formatted

Comment: @IlanHasanov shared

Comment: Save the input in the component's state. You can do things with the data from there.

Comment: @Jecoms , thank you for your response. Could you please give some examples?

Answer (score -2):

Use `Redux Form` You'll have a function `onSubmit` with all the input from the form.

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, I only intend on using Flux as it is a simple app.